# How to convert XML response to temp-table in OpenEdge Progress4GL?

Tags: web-services, soap, openedge, progress-4gl

Hello Progress4GL Developers,

I am trying to use progress to consume a SOAP API. At the moment, I am just using a opensource sample SOAP service called: http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL.

The following program works a dream (i.e user inputs country code such as "ESP" and details about Spain are showed to user). The result is stored in temp-table1 and temp-table2:

```
/******* Sample Application to show Progress4GL Consuming a SOAP API *************/

/******* VARIABLES ***************************************************************/
DEFINE VARIABLE lReturn AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hServer AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hPortType AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE capitalCity as LONGCHAR NO-UNDO.

DEFINE VARIABLE iCntryCode as char no-undo label "Country Code".
DEFINE VARIABLE oResponse as LONGCHAR no-undo.

/******* CONNECTION SETTINGS TO SOAP SERVICE *************************************/
CREATE SERVER hServer.
lReturn = hServer:CONNECT("-WSDL http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL"). 

IF lReturn = NO THEN DO:
 MESSAGE
  "Could not connect to WebService server".
 END.

/******* SETTING PORT TYPE *******************************************************/
RUN CountryInfoServiceSoapType SET hPortType ON SERVER hServer.

IF NOT VALID-HANDLE(hPortType) THEN DO:
 MESSAGE
  "Could not establish portType".
 END.

/****** USER UPDATE FORM**********************************************************/
UPDATE iCntryCode. 

/****** NAME OF DATA FUNCTION TO RUN *********************************************/
RUN FullCountryInfo IN hPortType (INPUT iCntryCode, OUTPUT oResponse) NO-ERROR.

/****** TEMP TABLE TO HOLD ALL CAPITAL CITY FIELDS *******************************/
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE temptable1 
SERIALIZE-NAME "sCapitalCity" 
    FIELD capitalCity AS CHAR XML-NODE-TYPE "text". 

/****** DATASET WHICH RUNS CONVERSION ********************************************/
DEFINE DATASET dsa SERIALIZE-NAME "FullCountryInfoResult" FOR temptable1. 

/***** TEMP TABLE TO HOLD ALL CURRENCY FIELDS ************************************/
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE temptable2 
SERIALIZE-NAME "sCurrencyISOCode" 
    FIELD currencyCode AS CHAR XML-NODE-TYPE "text". 

/****** DATASET WHICH RUNS CONVERSION ********************************************/
DEFINE DATASET dsb SERIALIZE-NAME "FullCountryInfoResult" FOR temptable2.

/****** POPULATE DATASET AND TEMP-TABLES FROM SOAP RESPONSE **********************/
DATASET dsa:READ-XML( "longchar", oResponse, ?, ?, ? ). 
DATASET dsb:READ-XML( "longchar", oResponse, ?, ?, ? ).

FOR EACH temptable1 no-lock, each temptable2 no-lock:
  DISPLAY temptable1.capitalcity temptable2.currencyCode.
END.

PAUSE 100.

/****** STOP CONNECTION TO SERVER ************************************************/
DELETE PROCEDURE hPortType.
  hServer:DISCONNECT().
  DELETE OBJECT hServer.
```

However, this sample web-service also has a procedure called FullCountryInfoAllCountries. This will give response for all countries. I have tried to re-factor the code above so that all temp-table1 and temp-table2 will be populated with all countries however I am having difficulty parsing the XML data.

I have tried experimenting with the NAMESPACE-URI, SERIALIZATION-NAME, and XML-NODE-NAME statements, but can't get it to work. The problem I have is that the XML response from FullCountryInfoAllCountries is structured differently to FullCountryInfo, and I always recieve an error along the lines of 'Namespace not found', or it will return nothing in the temp-tables.

Many Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can peek at the output by messaging the response (commented out), this can then be mapped to dataset, temp-table and field names:

```
define variable hs as handle no-undo.
define variable hp as handle no-undo.
define variable lcresponse as longchar no-undo.

define temp-table tt serialize-name "tCountryInfo" 
   field sISOCode as character
   field sName    as character
   .

define dataset ds serialize-name "FullCountryInfoAllCountriesResult" for tt. 

create server hs.
hs:connect( "-WSDL http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL" ). 

run CountryInfoServiceSoapType set hp on server hs.

run FullCountryInfoAllCountries in hp ( output lcresponse ).

// message string( substring( lcresponse, 1, 30000 ).

dataset ds:read-xml( "longchar", lcresponse, ?, ?, ? ). 

for each tt:
  display tt.
end.

delete procedure hp.
hs:disconnect().
delete object hs.
```

Comment: Spot on, was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much Stefan.

Comment: Glad to hear it - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers